# PHP urlencode in a loop?

Tags: php, html, urlencode

I am  new to php programming so please be patient. I have a little bit of code that makes a while loop through from 0 to 9 which provides a link to a page and adds some code to the url that acts as the get data for the url on page 2.

```
<?php $link_name = "Page 2"; ?>
<?php $company = "Super & Sprunklers"; ?>
<?php $id = 0; 

    while ($id <=10) {
        if ($id < 10) {
        echo "<a href=\"page2.php?id={$id}&company={$company}\">{$link_name}?id={$id}&company={$company}</a>";
    echo "<br />";

        } else {
    echo "<a href=\"page2.php\">{$link_name}</a>";
        }
    $id++;
    }
?>
```

This does work and generates the following links for the page:

```
Page 2?id=0&company=Super & Sprunklers
Page 2?id=1&company=Super & Sprunklers
Page 2?id=2&company=Super & Sprunklers
Page 2?id=3&company=Super & Sprunklers etc... to id=9
Page 2
```

However when I look at page 2 and see the get array for the two variables that I assign $id and $company to, because of the "&" I need to urlencode. This is my page 2 code, I was getting an warning when the page loaded without the variables so I gave them null values on page 2.

```
<pre>
<?php 

//print_r ($_GET);
//print_r ($GLOBALS);
$id = "";
$company = "";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {$id = $_GET['id'];}
if (isset($_GET['company'])) {$company = $_GET['company']; }
echo $id." ".$company;
?>
</pre>
```

However the page returns 0 Super

Everything after the "&" is missing.

My question is how do I add the urlencode function if {$company} is already in the echo statement. I have made this bit of code to make it work:

```
$companyencoded = urlencode($company);
```

And supplemented

```
echo "<a href=\"page2.php?id={$id}&company={$company}
```

with

```
echo "<a href=\"page2.php?id={$id}&company={$companyencoded}
```

But that involves makeing a new variable and when I look at the array of the $_GET on page 2 the variable $companyencoded does not exist?

Could you please explain what I'm doing wrong.

Many Thanks Asa

Comment: {urlencode($company)}

Comment: how about `echo "<a href...&company=".urlencode($company)."\">...</a>";` ?

Comment: You don't variable `$companyencoded` in the second page. `company` passed as param to get request can be accessed using `$_GET['company']` like you have coded in second page.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Linial I have already tried that method and the array split on page 2 making sprunklers not have a value.

Comment: Birdspider I tried your method too, but that gave a similer result to my get array on page 2, so thanks but no cigar.

Comment: Subir Kumar, thanks I figured out where the get variables where coming from. I tried to add $companyencoded, to the second page, but the variavble for the $_GET are in the url. id= &company= so that is where  those variables come from. Thanks for pointing me in the right directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have encoded at first place and need to decode on second place

```
<?php $link_name = "Page 2"; ?>
<?php $company = "Super & Sprunklers";
$url= urlencode("Super & Sprunklers");?>
<?php $id = 0; 

    while ($id <=10) {
        if ($id < 10) {
        echo "<a href=\"page2.php?id={$id}&company={$url}\">{$link_name}?id={$id}&company={$company}</a>";
    echo "<br />";

        } else {
    echo "<a href=\"page2.php\">{$link_name}</a>";
        }
    $id++;
    }
?>
```

in it for url i have encoded the charecter.
and can decode on page2.php

```
    <pre>
<?php 
$id = "";
$company = "";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {$id = $_GET['id'];}
if (isset($_GET['company'])) {$company = $_GET['company']; }
echo $id." ".  urldecode($company);
?>
</pre>
```

cheers peace of cake

Comment: Thanks can you explain why you assigned $url rather than urlencode $company? e.g $company = "Super & Sprunklers"; 
  $company = urlencode($company);

Comment: well that's your choice what ever you want to choose to do the task. main thing here is always encode the special characters and then don't forget to decode it back. well you are right i have created another variable which is unnecessary :p .

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer that works

```
<?php $link_name = "Page 2"; ?>
<?php $company = "Super & Sprunklers"; 
  $company = urlencode($company); ?>
<?php $id = 0; 

    while ($id <=10) {
        if ($id < 10) {
        echo "<a href=\"page2.php?id={$id}&company={$company}\">{$link_name}?id={$id}&company=".urldecode($company)."</a>";
    echo "<br />";

        } else {
    echo "<a href=\"page2.php\">{$link_name}</a>";
        }
    $id++;
    }
?>
```

In order to get page 2 to correctly show the correct array. Many thanks everyone. This is the line of code that was getting me so confused, $company = urlencode($company). I thought that this would be like making a circular reference in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually a simple thing.

Use urlencode() when passing the company name as a query string. and on page2, make sure to urldecode() that value.

Here is your URL:

```
echo "<a href=\"page2.php?id={$id}&company=".urlencode($company)."\">{$link_name}?id={$id}&company={$company}</a>";
```

and on page2, use in this way.

```
$company = urldecode($_GET['company']);
```

This should work properly.

Comment: Hello, when I tried &company=".urlencode($company)." it split the array on page 2 to equal id=>0 [company] => Super [Sprunklers]=> . The  super global array $_GET ought to automatically add the urldecode when echoing to page 2.

Comment: Yes it is..but decoded or not, it should print without any problem. I tested it locally and both work properly